# SwiftUI: Problems with TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I am pretty new to the swift community so I apologize if this is a low-brainer.

I have the following problem: I have an app that is throwing the following warning since I changed to a TabView Layout:

> "[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at `UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy` to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. 
>   `Table view: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x7fcc03055600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 414 852); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e25500>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000200bf20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 83, 0}; dataSource: (null)>`"

I successfully re-created the problem with a straight-forward structure (see below). I would be very happy for any suggestions what's going on here:

**1) Model**

```
class PersonList {

    var personList: [Person]

    init() {
        personList = [Person]()
        personList.append(Person(surName: "Jane", name: "Smith"))
        personList.append(Person(surName: "John", name: "Smith"))
    }
}

class Person: Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()
    var surName: String
    var name: String

    init(surName: String, name: String) {
        self.surName = surName
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**2) Single Tab View**

```
struct TestView: View {

    let personList: [Person]

    var body: some View {
        List (personList) { person in
            Text("Hallo \(person.name)")
        }
    }
}
```

**3) Content View that includes two Tabs (will be more complicated in the actual app)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var personList = PersonList()

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Test")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 1")
            }
            TestView(personList: personList.personList)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises as soon as you click on tab 2 and then go back to tab 1.

Many thanks in advance and best regards,

Julian

Comment: Ok, warning is here (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4). So, what's the problem? Views work fine, tab switching works fine... anything?

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. Indeed, everything works fine I am just wondering what Xcode is warning me about?

Comment: There are many such. If any bothers you, then submit feedback to Apple, otherwise, if everything works as expected - just ignore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Only thing I am worrying is whether Apple would deny when submitting to the App Store due to any such warnings...

Comment: It is not your warning - it's their warning =)